# Get a reference to the event listener from a middleware

Tags: node.js, events, middleware

Is there a way to get a reference to the `event listener` as in the following stub?

```
socket.on('login',login)
```

Could I get a reference to `socket` inside the function `login`?

```
// Login module

module.exports = ({username, password}, next) => {
   // How to refer socket here?
}
```

I cannot pass `socket` into the middleware, as the library I am using underneath doesn't recognize the third argument and I would not want to alter its regular behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`login.bind({socket: socket})`
Then in login function use `this.socket`

Comment: I made it to work with `login.bind(socket)` and then accessing socket object it via `this` i.e `this === socket`